# CollectionViewSource FilterDescriptions with LiveFiltering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collectionviewsource

I am binding integer value to collectionview source filtering properties. Is it possible to filter the viewsource withing xaml without using code behind.

View is in continuous refresh with order value and sorting

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding ItemSource, ElementName=TestItems }" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" IsLiveFilteringRequested="True" >
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName= "Order"  />
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
      <CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>
        <clr:String>Order</clr:String>
      </CollectionViewSource.LiveSortingProperties>

      <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        <clr:String>Order</clr:String>
      </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
```

if  order becomes Invalid collectionviewsource should be hidden or collapsed

Comment: A CollectionViewSource Filters on an Event, there is no way to handle an event with out code, however that code doesn't have to be in the View, though 90% of the time that is the correct place as filtering is a view functions as are grouping and sorting

Comment: If you don't want to use the default mechanism though you could write your own ICollectionView